# parallel execution of multiple methods - on_navigate taipy

Tags: taipy

is it possible for parallel execution of methods in the on_navigate? I tried ThreadPoolExecutor but showed an error Working outside of the application context.

```
def on_navigate(state: State, page_name: str) -> str:
    page_actions = {
        "Overview": [update_total_projects],
        "Create": [create_update_available_projects],
        "Edit": [refresh_edit_page_elements, edit_update_available_projects],
        "Live": [live_update_available_projects, update_available_Machines,
                 update_available_Materials, update_available_Materials_Matrix, update_available_Materials_dis,
                 update_available_Applicators, update_available_nozzle_s, update_available_nozzle_d, update_available_nozzle_l]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions exist to simplify the use of thread and avoid these issues. You can either use:

- [`invoke_callback`](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#long-running-callbacks): you can use it inside a *Thread* and use the *State* inside your function.
- [`invoke_long_callback`](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#long-running-callbacks-in-a-thread): is using the `invoke_callback` behind the scene to create a simpler syntax to make asynchronous calls.

Here are some examples of code (Taipy 3.0):

For [`invoke_long_callback`](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#long-running-callbacks-in-a-thread):

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, State, get_state_id, notify, invoke_callback
from threading import Thread


gui = Gui(pages={"/":"<|navbar|>", "page1":"page1", "page2":"page2"})

def heavy_function_done(state: State):
    # Now the State can be used to update the user interface
    notify(state, "info", "The task was done!")

def heavy_function_in_thread(state_id: str):
    invoke_callback(gui, state_id, heavy_function_done, [])

def on_navigate(state: State, page_name: str) -> str:
    thread = Thread(target=heavy_function_in_thread,
                    args=[get_state_id(state)])
    thread.start()
    return page_name
    
gui.run()
```

For [`invoke_long_callback`](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#long-running-callbacks-in-a-thread):

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, State, notify, invoke_long_callback

def heavy_function_done(state: State):
    # Now the State can be used to update the user interface
    notify(state, "info", "The task was done!")

def iddle():
    # Function without the state that can give results
    pass

def on_navigate(state: State, page_name: str) -> str:
    invoke_long_callback(state, iddle, [],
                         heavy_function_done, [])
    return page_name
    
Gui(pages={"/":"<|navbar|>", "page1":"page1", "page2":"page2"}).run()
```

Comment: Still, I believe there is a limit to several parallel threads I can use.  
def thread_action(action, state_id):
        invoke_callback(gui_multi_pages, state_id, action, [])

    state_id = get_state_id(state)

    # Using ThreadPoolExecutor to limit to 4 threads
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for action in actions:
            executor.submit(thread_action, action, state_id)

if its more than 4, it shows the same error

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your issue. Could you edit your question to create a reproducible code with your issue?

Comment: i tried replicating the issue but i belive since the application am building Is pretty big that is causing the issue. unfortunately i am also unable to replicate this in a small code.